# how to load more data binding?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

when i tab to itemFooter , databinding will getdata and load continue

```
    public void getFeed()
    {
        waittingopen();
        if (listRSS != null && listRSS.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Article> listArticle = getArticle();

            if (listArticle.Count > 0)
            {
                if (loadmor != null && list.Items.Contains(loadmor))
                {
                    list.Items.Remove(loadmor);
                }

                #region  add item
                for (int i = 0; i < listArticle.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataDetail dataDetail;
                    if (i == 0 && dtListBoxx.Count == 0)
                        dataDetail = new dataDetail { title = listArticle[i].title, feedName = listRSS[indexLoadmor].name, Type = "itemBigContent", isVisileLineLeft = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed, isVisileBook = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed };
                    else
                        dataDetail = new dataDetail { title = listArticle[i].title, feedName = listRSS[indexLoadmor].name, Type = "itemContent", isVisileLineLeft = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed, isVisileBook = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed };
                    dtListBoxx.Add(dataDetail);
                }
                #endregion

                if (intLoad == 0)
                {
                    listArticle.Clear();
                    listArticle = null;
                    indexLoadmor++;
                    intLoad++;
                    getFeed();
                }
                else
                {
                    intLoad = 0;
                    dataDetail dataLoadmoreItem = new dataDetail { Type = "itemFooter" };
                    dtListBoxx.Add(dataLoadmoreItem);

                    this.list.ItemsSource = dtListBoxx;
                }
                waittingClose();
            }
            else
            {
                getfeed = new Getfeed(listRSS[indexLoadmor].link.ToString(), "", listRSS[indexLoadmor].rid, intLoad);
                getfeed.onComplete += new Getfeed.DownloadComplete(getfeed_onComplete);
                if (intLoad == 1)
                    intLoad = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

how do i can load more data by using this.list.ItemsSource = dtListBoxx ? I tried but listbox is not updated when dataDetail add item

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. It automatically raises `OnCollectionChanged` event to notify view that some changes in collection are occurred.

Comment: thank Ku6opr !
How do you change the value of the Visible in classData the UI will automatically change

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your class. See example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: I tried using INotifyPropertyChanged, but when I change the Ui does not change, for example: when I change the value from true to false isChecked, it appears unchanged, although the value has changed

Comment: Your setter should look like: `set { isChecked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }`

Comment: thank !
But i want when i back from Page B to Page A , i set isCheck = true in Page B and check Box in Page A isChecked = true .

Comment: Bind two `ChechBoxes` to one global object, accessible from both pages